# How to send additional params to serverside from store while creating new items or updating exsiting one

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid panel with some records. But elements of this grid panel are children. So, when I am creating a new record in grid, or updating an existing one, I`d like to send additional param to server side as parent id (parent is one for the table). I am using direct store.

I know, that there are remote Filters, but it seems, that they sent only on read action, not on create or update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TO SEND THE extraParams ALWAYS NOT ONLY ON READ OPERATIONS (CREATE, DESTROY, UPDATE)**

I extended

> Ext.data.proxy.Direct

and override

> doRequest

It worked like a charm.

Using ExtJs 4.1.1

The original code is:

```
if (operation.action == 'read') {
            // We need to pass params
            method = fn.directCfg.method;
            args = method.getArgs(params, me.paramOrder, me.paramsAsHash);
        } else {
            args.push(request.jsonData);
        }
```

I changed it to:

```
    method = fn.directCfg.method;
    args = method.getArgs(params, me.paramOrder, me.paramsAsHash);

    if(operation.action !== 'read'){
         args.push(request.jsonData);
    }
```

Took the idea from here https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282879-ExtraParams-Store-Create

**Notice**: your store will have a proxy of whatever you put on the alias of the class you created. Your alias will be like `alias : 'proxy.mycompanydirect'` then your store will have a proxy type `'mycompanydirect'`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send Extra Parameters use the extraParams property on the Proxy

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-extraParams

Comment: yes, it will be sent on read, but still not send on update method

Comment: I'm dealing with the same @ArtemTheArtem , did you ever get a fix for this ?

Comment: @code4jhon Sorry, but as I remember, we didn't solve this in this way. Perhaps, we make some special request or something like this, but nothing with extra params

Comment: @ArtemTheArtem I found a solution for this and posted it as an answer just in case you ever need this again (only 4 years late :) ) .

Answer (score 0):

**extraParams** :

> Object4 Extra parameters that will be included on every request.
>   Individual requests with params of the same name will override these
>   params when they are in conflict.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                  // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
                  autoDestroy: true,
                  model: 'Plant',
                  proxy: {
                  extraParams: {name: 'dfds'}, // to send extra parmas 
                  ...
                  }
            });
```